# IOS audio recorder with VOR function and black screen

Tags: audio, ipad-app

I'm looking for an app for Ipad which is able to record sounds for very long time for surveillance purpose.

The requirements are:

- Save file in a compressed formad (i.e. mp3)
- Register only if there is noise / voice (no long silences). Sony called this functionality VOR on its physical audio recorder, some other apps call it sound detection.
- Work in standby mode or at least switch off the screen to save battery

Do you know any app which satisfies this requirements?